# Reset Linking.getInitialURL() when BackHandler.exitApp()

Tags: react-native

I am using `Linking.getInitialURL()` to determine if my App got started by tapping a Deeplinking-URL.

My App gets closed by the standard behavior (`BackHandler.exitApp()`) when clicking the hardware back button on Android.

If the user closes the App (via the back button), after it first got startet by an URL, and then opens it from the background (not by clicking a url), I don't want `Linking.getInitialURL()` to get triggered again with the old URL from the first start. Is there any way to reset `Linking.getInitialURL()`?

I appreciate any Help or other Ideas to solve my Problem!

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getLink = async () => {
      const link = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      console.log('getLink: ', link)
    }
    getLink();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', handleDynamicLink);
    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleDynamicLink);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleDynamicLink = (link: any) => {
    console.log('handleLink: ', link)
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
            <Button
            onPress={() => {BackHandler.exitApp()}}
            title="TestButton"/>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```